# How can I make Chrome and Firefox show badly formed XML fully?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, firefox, runtime-error, data-dump

I want Chrome and Firefox to show badly formed XML in full plaintext format instead of telling me that it's badly formed and showing the first few characters of the offending plaintext.

This could potentially be useful for any web developer when dumping variables and such.

Comment: Did you try the  view source option?

Comment: A `text/plain` header would show the plain text, but you'd need to know beforehand whether it's broken or not

Comment: View source does work but I'd prefer not having to do any extra steps (not even hitting ctrl-u).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for Firefox, but this is simply the way that XML is handled in Chrome; the parser is draconian, and error messages in parsing are raised to the user via the UI that you're unhappy with. :)

A quick search of the bug database doesn't show any similar requests to point you to, so I'd suggest filing a bug with your feature suggestion via http://new.crbug.com/ I can't promise that anyone will implement it quickly (especially given view-source as a viable workaround), but at least the suggestion will be tracked in the system for others to find and vote for via stars.

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer so late - In the meantime I've come up with an alternative solution of implementing a dump GET parameter interpreted by the webapp which uses pain/text MIME type in this case and outputs some dump info.  It has proven to be a viable feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use a processing instruction to wrap the malformed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <test>
    <good>Me &amp; my dad</good>
      <?_borderline 

      <bad>Me & my matches</bad>

      ?>
  </test>
```